# vertical stacked bar chart using D3.js from Json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

i want a vertical stacked bar chart with x axis and y axis labels and tool tip showing values and legends. please show me how to reduce the size of the graph also....

Now bar stacked bar chart is showing with very big size But no x and y axis... amd tool tip and legends is also not coming...

```
            var w = 700,
            h = 500;
            var margin = {top: 25, right: 75, bottom: 85, left: 85};
            // create canvas
            var svg = d3.select("#bar-chart").append("svg:svg")
            .attr("class", "chart")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h )
            .append("svg:g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(10,470)");

            x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, w-50]);
            y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, h-50]);
            z = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["yellow", "grey", "orange"]);

            var colors =    [["Cat 980", "#D0D0D0"],
                             ["Kom500", "#4DAF4A"],
                             ["Kom501", "#D0D0D0"],
                            ["Kom502", "#D0D0D0"]];

            console.log("RAW MATRIX---------------------------");
        // 4 columns: ID,c1,c2,c3
            var matrix = [
                [ 1,  5871, 8916, 2868],
                [ 2, 10048, 2060, 6171],
                [ 3, 16145, 8090, 8045],
                [ 4,   990,  940, 6907]
            ];
            console.log(matrix);

            console.log("REMAP---------------------------");
            var remapped =["c1","c2","c3"].map(function(dat,i){
                return matrix.map(function(d,ii){
                    return {x: ii, y: d[i+1] };
                });
            });
            console.log(remapped);

            console.log("LAYOUT---------------------------");
            var stacked = d3.layout.stack()(remapped);
            console.log(stacked);

            var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(d3.range(stacked.length)).rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05); 
            // ternary operator to determine if global or local has a larger scale
            var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(remapped)]).range([h, 0]);

            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).tickFormat(function(d) { return stacked[d].keyword; }).orient("bottom");
            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left").ticks(5);





            x.domain(stacked[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(stacked[stacked.length - 1], function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]);

            // show the domains of the scales              
            console.log("x.domain(): " + x.domain())
            console.log("y.domain(): " + y.domain())
            console.log("------------------------------------------------------------------");

            // Add a group for each column.
            var valgroup = svg.selectAll("g.valgroup")
            .data(stacked)
            .enter().append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "valgroup")
            .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); })
            .style("stroke", function(d, i) { return d3.rgb(z(i)).darker(); });

         // xAxis
            svg.append("g") // Add the X Axis
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h) + ")")
                .call(xAxis)
                .selectAll("text")
                    .style("text-anchor", "end")
                    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                    .attr("dy", ".15em")
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                            return "rotate(-25)";
                    })
                    ;
            // yAxis
            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0 ,0)")
                .call(yAxis)
                ;
            // xAxis label

            svg.append("text") 
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w / 2) + " ," + (h + margin.bottom - 5) +")")
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text("Keyword");
            //yAxis label
            svg.append("text")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                    .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
                    .attr("x", 0 - (h / 2))
                    .attr("dy", "1em")
                    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .text("Product");

            // Add a rect for each date.
            var rect = valgroup.selectAll("rect")
            .data(function(d){return d;})
            .enter().append("svg:rect")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return -y(d.y0) - y(d.y); })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
            .attr("width", x.rangeBand());

            // add legend   
            var legend = svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "legend")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(70,10)")
                    ;
            var legendRect = legend.selectAll('rect').data(colors);

            legendRect.enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", w - 65)
                .attr("y", 0)                                       // use this to flip horizontal
                .attr("width", 10)
                .attr("height", 10)
                .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                    return i * 20;
                })
            //  .attr("x", function(d, i){return w - 65 - i * 70}) // use this to flip horizontal
                .style("fill", function(d) {
                    return d[1];
                });

            var legendText = legend.selectAll('text').data(colors);

            legendText.enter()
                .append("text")
                .attr("x", w - 52)
                .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                    return i * 20 + 9;
                })
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d[0];
                });
            svg.select("g.x").call(xAxis);
            svg.select("g.y").call(yAxis);
```